# How find text in file and get lines up and down according to pattern

Tags: linux, command-line, split

How can I find in file particular text '12345' and get all lines up and down till to the 'Received notification:' using linux console commands without hardcoding numbers of lines for up and down?

**Received notification:**

Random text

Random text

...

**12345**

random text

...

Random text

**Received notification:**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach:

```
 $ awk '/str1/ {p=1}; p; /str2/ {p=0}' file
```

- When it finds str1, then makes variable p=1. It just prints lines when p==1. This is accomplished with the p condition. If it is true, it performs the default awk action, that is, print $0. Otherwise, it does not.
- When it finds str2, then makes variable p=0. As this condition is checked after p condition, it will print the line in which str2 appears for the first time.